# list index python and list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x

```
list1 = [48, 33, 46, 46, 87, 11, 50, 99, 65, 87]
list2 = [48, 33, 46]
duplicates = [list1.pop(list1.index(i)) for i in list1 if i in list2]
```

So if I try to print out duplicates, it will have[48,46]
this is a homework and the question is what
the code was expected to do and explain how the code needs to be changed to obtain the expected result.

Comment: and so you think StackOverflow will do your homework ?

Comment: Your homework gave you that list comprehension as example code? Don't *ever* use a list-comprehension that way. List comprehensions are for *transforming data*, do *not* use operations that cause side-effects, e.g. like `list1.pop`, because that isn't what list-comprehensions are for.

Comment: looks like you're removing items while iterating, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: `list1.pop()` has side-effects but return something, so it may be valid. When you query a database through list comprehension, you probably enable a lot of side effects (caching, etc...) but it's ok. Here it's not valid because you're removing items while iterating.

Answer (score 0):

that:

```
[list1.pop(list1.index(i)) for i in list1 if i in list2]
```

is wrong because it removes items from `list1` while iterating on it. So you skip some elements.

Making a copy of the input list fixes it somehow:

```
list1 = [48, 33, 46, 46, 87, 11, 50, 99, 65, 87]
list2 = [48, 33, 46]
duplicates = [list1.pop(list1.index(i)) for i in list1[:] if i in list2]
```

now I get: `[48, 33, 46, 46]`. To remove duplicates in the result, just convert to `set` and back to `list`

```
list(set([48, 33, 46, 46])) => [48, 33, 46]
```

note that your `list1.pop(list1.index(i))` is really sub-optimal, but required because the indexes are shifted when an item is removed, and you don't care about changing `list1`

To compute duplicates just do:

```
duplicates = [i for i in list1 if i in list2]
```

you get the same result, and it doesn't change `list1`.